# Block element is not displayed

Tags: html, css

Hello I have the following code in html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@900&family=Nunito+Sans:wght@300;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <header class="header">
        <div class="navigation">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="nav-links">
                
                <h1 class="logo">Polaris</h1>
                    
                <div class="navigation-links">
                    
                <div class="main"><a href="#!"> Главная</a></div>
                <div class="main">Наши услуги</div>
                <div class="main">О Компании</div>
                <div class="main">Контакты</div>
            </div>

            <div class="free-consultation">
                Бесплатная консультация
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <div class="main">
        content
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And in css

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a:link, a:hover,a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.header{
    background-image: url('../img/bg-img.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
  
}


.navigation{
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.navigation::before{
    
    position: absolute;
    right:310px;
    top:0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0.5px;
    height: 132px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}

.container{
    margin-left: 53px;
    margin-right: 83px;
    margin-top: 34px;
}

.logo{
    font-family: 'Inter';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 25px;
line-height: 125%;
/* or 31px */

letter-spacing: 0.11em;
color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
width: 128px;
height: 31px;
}

.nav-links{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
   margin-bottom: 35px;
   z-index: 1;
}

.navigation-links{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    column-gap: 60px;

font-family: 'Nunito Sans';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;

color: #FFFFFF;
}

.free-consultation{
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans',sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 00;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;

color: #FFFFFF;
}
.free-consultation::before{
    z-index: 11212;
    position: absolute;
    left:-68px;
    top:-10px;
    content: '';
    background-image: url('../img/Ellipse\ 2.svg');
    
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    
}

.free-consultation::before::before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.main{
}
```

here is the link to codesandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-davinci-1dqujt?file=/style.css

For some reason, the next block element is not displayed on the next line, it's displayed inside another block(which is on the background image). Why is that so? Can someone help me please?

Comment: `<header>` has `position: absolute;`, it means that it's taken out of the flow. That's why your `<div class="main">` isn't "on the next line"

Comment: Oh okay, but how can I make it work correct? So that image is full height and width, but next block is one next line?

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that your `<header class="header">` is taken out of the flow byt this rule:

```
.header{
  position: absolute;
}
```

> ### Absolute Positioning
>
> Giving an item position: absolute or position: fixed removes it from flow, and any space that it would have taken up is removed.
> [Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/In_Flow_and_Out_of_Flow#absolute_positioning)

What you want is probably to have the background on your `body` element.

### Making sure that the body will take at least 100% of the height

```
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

### Giving the body the background-image

```
body {
  background-image: url("./bg-img.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

### Removing the absolute position related code on header

```
.header {
  /*  
  background-image: url("./bg-img.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; 
  height: 100vh;
  */
  width: 100%;
}
```